# How to get all possible branch with python anytree

Tags: python, list, tree, anytree

I'm using [anytree](https://pypi.org/project/anytree/) currently to generate my search tree, how do I get all possible branch starting from the root node in list format

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree, AsciiStyle

f = Node("f")
b = Node("b", parent=f)
a = Node("a", parent=b)
d = Node("d", parent=b)
c = Node("c", parent=d)
e = Node("e", parent=d)
g = Node("g", parent=f)
i = Node("i", parent=g)
h = Node("h", parent=i)
print(RenderTree(f, style=AsciiStyle()).by_attr())
```

Current Tree:

```
f 
|-- b
|   |-- a
|   +-- d
|       |-- c
|       +-- e
+-- g
    +-- i
        +-- h
```

wanted output (treeBranch):

> > [[f,b,a], [f,b,d,c], [f,b,d,e], [f,g,i,h]]

I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this, open to any suggestion.

I want to use this list to check if a new path from user exists in the tree, for example:

```
newPath = [f, b]

for branch in treeBranch:
    if newPath in branch:
        return true
    else:
        // add new path to tree
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to have the root path for every leaf node.
Just use the [PreOrderIter](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/2.8.0/api/anytree.iterators.html#anytree.iterators.preorderiter.PreOrderIter) with a `filter_` to retrieve the leaf nodes:

```py
print(list(PreOrderIter(f, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf)))
[a, c, e, h]
```

And then access the [path attribute](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/2.8.0/api/anytree.node.html#anytree.node.nodemixin.NodeMixin.path) on every node:

```py
print([list(leaf.path) for leaf in PreOrderIter(f, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf)])
[[f,b,a], [f,b,d,c], [f,b,d,e], [f,g,i,h]]
```

If you like to have the path from any node in the tree towards the leaf nodes:

```py
def allpaths(start):
    skip = len(start.path) - 1
    return [leaf.path[skip:] for leaf in PreOrderIter(start, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf)]
print(allpaths(b))
[(b, a), (b, d, c), (b, d, e)]
```

Please note that there is also a [Walker](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/2.8.0/api/anytree.walker.html), which serves the path from any node to another one.

Comment: Hey, the above solution does not seem to be working as so in anytree (2.8.0). Only `print(list(PreOrderIter(f, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf)))
` is giving me all the branches in a list but they are as a Node Object, for ex:

[Node('/f/b/a'), Node('/f/b/d/c'), Node('/f/b/d/e'), Node('/f/g/i/h')]

How may I get the data out of the node object in the form: [[f,b,a], [f,b,d,c], [f,b,d,e], [f,g,i,h]] ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution from @c0fec0de does not work like that anymore in anytree 2.8.0. I tried the following:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree, AsciiStyle, PreOrderIter
f = Node("f")
b = Node("b", parent=f)
a = Node("a", parent=b)
d = Node("d", parent=b)
c = Node("c", parent=d)
e = Node("e", parent=d)
g = Node("g", parent=f)
i = Node("i", parent=g)
h = Node("h", parent=i)
print(RenderTree(f, style=AsciiStyle()).by_attr())
```

Which gave me the following tree:

```
f
|-- b
|   |-- a
|   +-- d
|       |-- c
|       +-- e
+-- g
    +-- i
        +-- h
```

After this, to get a list of all the branches in the tree I tried:

```
>>> print(list(PreOrderIter(f, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf)))
[Node('/f/b/a'), Node('/f/b/d/c'), Node('/f/b/d/e'), Node('/f/g/i/h')]
```

And since the response is in a Node Object, to convert it to a list of nodes as string, I did the following:

```
>>> lst = list(PreOrderIter(f, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf))
>>> print(lst)
[Node('/f/b/a'), Node('/f/b/d/c'), Node('/f/b/d/e'), Node('/f/g/i/h')]
>>> f = [str(i)[7:-2].split(i.separator) for i in lst]
>>> print(f)
[['f', 'b', 'a'], ['f', 'b', 'd', 'c'], ['f', 'b', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'i', 'h']]
```

Would be keen to see if there are better ways to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

@michael-westen my solution to exploit fully .name and .path and to avoid strings manipulation:

`leaves = [node_i.name for node_i in PreOrderIter(f.root, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf)]`

`branches = [[node_i.name for node_i in data_i.path]  for data_i in PreOrderIter(f.root, filter_=lambda node: node.is_leaf)]`